# Docker + Windows 10

Tags: windows, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try work with docker on Windows 10 and I have 2 problems.

First:

if i try do 
Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

MAINTAINER Nikita rassamakhin "nrj.tomsk@gmail.com"

COPY /nginx-conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY /nginx-conf/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

and this docker-compose

```
fpm:
    container_name: php7
    image: php:7.0.2-fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    links:
        - mysql
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - fpm

mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

i have 403 error on try open localhost.
if i try add app section in docker compose like this

```
app:
    container_name: app
    image: ubuntu:trusty
    volumes:
        - www/:/var/www
fpm:
    container_name: php7
    image: php:7.0.2-fpm
    working_dir: "/var/www"
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - fpm
    volumes_from:
        - fpm

mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

app conteiner start and exit with code 0, without logs about error.

How i can fix this? What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> app conteiner start and exit with code 0, without logs about error.

You need to set a `command` or `entrypoint` for the `app` container. The default is probably `bash` which exits immediately. Exit code 0 means "exited with no error".